# jQuery countdown onExpiry function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery countdown from http://keith-wood.name. I'm trying to do something on expiry of countdown timer but I have no luck doing so...

my code is a small mixture of jquery and php. basically I get the end date/time from server side.

this is my code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".defaultCountdown'.$randKey.'").countdown({
        until: new Date('.$end_date.'),
        onExpiry: new Date('.$end_date.'),
        compact: true

    });


});
</script>
```

the code above works fine but when I try to do something on expiry, the coutdown timer stops working and it won't display anything.

I tried this:

```
onExpiry: function () { 
    alert('We have lift off!'); 
}
```

and this is the edited code which doesn't work:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".defaultCountdown'.$randKey.'").countdown({
        until: new Date('.$end_date.'),
        onExpiry: new Date('.$end_date.'),
        compact: true

    });
        onExpiry: function () { 
        alert("We have lift off!"); 
    }

});
</script>
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the anonymous function to execute on countdown completion to the `onExpiry` parameter. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".defaultCountdown'.$randKey.'").countdown({
        until: new Date('.$end_date.'),
        onExpiry: function () { 
            alert("We have lift off!"); 
        },
        compact: true
    });
});
```

Comment: I will accept this when it lets me.. you sir are a genius